# Wait for JS load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a problem with the js load at my spec script.
I used `js: true` and `wait_for_ajax`, but it does not work well, cause I use `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count` to access the email.

Is there another way to make the test wait until js is loading?

```
select 'Colombia', from: 'country_box'
sleep 10 
select 'Bogota', from: 'state_select' 
sleep 10 
select 'Bogota', from: 'city_select'
```

I tried this, but this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be worrying about waiting for JS (nor using any type of `wait_for_ajax`)- instead you should be asserting/expecting for visible page changes that indicate the state of the page is in a condition to move on in the test.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank u for help me. 
My question is, how do I insert a wait for a dropdown to be clickable (show available options) after?

Comment: @LucasAlvine You need to provide enough info for someone to understand what your page is doing. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add enough info to your question to explain what is actually happening on the page, the code you've tried,  a sample of the HTML you're dealing with, and the full error message you're getting .  If it's just to wait some amount of time for an HTML select box to appear on the page then the sleep you show should have worked (it's not a good solution but it should have worked)